# Filter List with Agera

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a List and I want to filter it based on some predicate 
, this can be easly done using '`RxJava`' using filter operator , but I can't find an equivalent in Agera and docs are not clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Predicate.apply(T)` and `Predicates` utility class, you can use them via `.check()`. See [docs](https://github.com/google/agera/wiki/Compiled-repositories#operators)